# Creating a one-to-many relationship EF Core - update-database fail

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I wants to create a one-to-many relationship.

The plan is as follows: One Customer can have multiple Bikes. Below I present the data models.

**Bike Model**

```
public class Bike
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Brand { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Size { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
        public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime AddedBike { get; set; }
    }
```

**Customer Model**

```
public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Telephone")]
        public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime DateTimeAdd { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayName("Last Update Customer")]
        public DateTime EditDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Bike> Bike { get; set; }
    }
```

**DBContext**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Bike> Bikes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Migration is going well. However, update-database causes this error:

PM> update-database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidOperationException: There is no entity type mapped to the table 'Bikes' used in a data operation. Either add the corresponding entity type to the model or specify the column types in the data operation.
...
There is no entity type mapped to the table 'Bikes' used in a data operation. Either add the corresponding entity type to the model or specify the column types in the data operation.

Where is the mistake I am making?

Comment: How do you update the database, can you share the initial model? From your question, I can not produce this error.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: With your model and DbContext, I can migrate and update database successfully. Can you share some other configuration in your project?

Comment: @KamilM The models does no match with ones in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Yes, because this repo has last working code. When I change models update-database not working.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you switch to EF 5?

Comment: @Klamsi no. I use EF Core.

Comment: @KamilM Sorry, I mixed it up: Yes, EF Core 5. (EF is still with Core,.NET without Core)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it worked. I finally deleted all migrations, created a new migration and updated the database.

I then added the relationships in the models, did the migration again and updated the database and it worked.

My models look like this

**Bike.cs**

```
public class Bike
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Brand { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Size { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime AddedBike { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

**Customer.cs**

```
 public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Telephone")]
        public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime DateTimeAdd { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayName("Last Update Customer")]
        public DateTime Edit { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Bike> Bike { get; set; }
    }
```